# I'm trying to draw something with float value in c# but I'm not successful

Tags: c#, graphics

I want to draw some sort graphics on winform using following code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Pen myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Red);
            Graphics handler = this.CreateGraphics();


            double[] nextPt = new double[2];
            double[] maurerPt = new double[2];
            for (int index = 1; index < 361; index++)
            {
                nextPt = calcRose(index * d);

                //this line is incorrect but Drawline only accept Point which is int
                //and valued are in fractions thats why I use double
                handler.DrawLine(maurerPt[0], maurerPt[1], nextPt[0], nextPt[1];

                nextPt.CopyTo(maurerPt,2);
            }

            myPen.Dispose();
            handler.Dispose();

        }
```

the problem is I want to create some sort of mathematic graph something called "maruer rose"
and since my lines value are in fractions so I can't use Point which it  only accept int values

how can I feed drawline with double or float value?

regards.

Comment: Graphics.DrawLine() has an overload that accepts PointF.  Only draw in the Paint event btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hans should have posted his comment as an answer, but he is correct on both accounts.  `DrawLine()` has an overload that accepts a `PointF`, so that's not a problem.

Your next issue will be figuring out why your graph seems to disappear randomly.  You should do *all* of your drawing in a Control's Paint event or, if in a derived class, by overriding `OnPaint()`, always drawing to the supplied Graphics object (`e.Graphics`).

There will be times that your control repaints itself, perhaps because it was minimized, its dimensions were changed, whatever.  Your code only paints when a button is clicked, which means that a system forced re-paint will wipe out your graph.

Next, your code has a potential memory "leak".  What happens if anything between creating the pen/Graphics objects and calling Dispose() on them?  In this specific case your program would likely just crash, but in general and more importantly, your calls to `Dispose()` will not occur and you have temporarily "leaked" some native resources.

You should be wrapping the creation of types that implement `IDisposable` in `using` statements, i.e.

```
using( var myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Red) )
using( var handler = this.CreateGraphics() )
{
    // use 'myPen' and 'handler' here
}
```

This construct is actually a try/finally block, so even if something inside the curlies throws an exception `Dispose()` will still be called.